# Is there any code assist editor?

Tags: d3.js

How can I use code assist with d3 library?
aptana or anything, I try to that with Aptana,but it was not available.

Comment: why didn;t it work in aptana? aptana has content assist you just turn it on in the dropdown menu

Comment: Is it possible to apply D3 library? Where is the dropdown menu?

Comment: what version of aptana are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For code assist in Aptana 3:

1. Choose Window in the main menu Go to Preferences
2. Choose Aptana Studio → Content Assist
3. Look at the Auto-display content assist
4. You will see a drop down menu
5. Click drop-down menu and select Default delay.

This will give you content assist.

In Aptana 2:

To get the code assist working just change the default editor for .js files from JavaScript editor to Aptana JS editor (Go to Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations, then select *.js in the top list. Aptana JS Editor in the bottom list, click the "Default" button).

Comment: thanks a lot, actually I using Aptana 3. But I will try to work with your answer.