# Add javascript code assist for d3.js in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, aptana, code-assist

I am trying to add javascript code assist in Aptana Studio 3, working with code using the d3 javascript library d3.v3.js, which I have placed in the same dir as my javascript file that uses it. My project is an Aptana "Web" project.

I followed the first part (Aptana 3) of this answer: [Is there any code assist editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646791/is-there-any-code-assist-editor) - but it didn't give me the d3 code assist.

I noticed that it I don't have the option to choose "Aptana JS Editor" for *.js in the File Associations (see my second screenshot). Could it be the root of the problem? Clicking the "Add" button trying to add "Aptana JS Editor" to the options (see my last screenshot) there is no such option.

The Aptana Studio 3 version is: Build 3.4.2.201308081805, and my OS is Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit. Thanks for your help.

[image: Screenshot of the Context Assist menu]

[image: Screenshot of the File Associations]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that the following link might be of assistance
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646791/is-there-any-code-assist-editor